# Unable to run MongoDB server when using multiple IP addresses in bindIp configuration Option in Mongod version 3.6.5

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use multiple IP addresses in the bindIp configuration option and after saving the configuration changes, the mongodb server won't start. The same thing is working in MongoDB version 3.4

Here is the configuration settings:

```
    # network interfaces
net:
  port: 36784
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.0.0.226
```

Here 10.0.0.226 is the private IP address of the EC2 instance.

The same type of configuration was working in earliers versions of MongoDB more specifically in v3.4

If I use bindIp to 0.0.0.0, then of course it allows remote connections to all the IP addresses.

Once i restart the server, i am getting the following error:

```
    mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-06-25 05:36:45 UTC; 15s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 1570 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 1570 (code=exited, status=48)

Jun 25 05:36:45 ip-10-0-1-69 systemd[1]: Stopped High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Jun 25 05:36:45 ip-10-0-1-69 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Jun 25 05:36:45 ip-10-0-1-69 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
Jun 25 05:36:45 ip-10-0-1-69 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 25 05:36:45 ip-10-0-1-69 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here is the logs files content:

```
    2018-06-25T05:07:38.842+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-06-25T05:07:38.842+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
2018-06-25T05:13:43.192+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1390 port=36784 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-10-0-1-69
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.5
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca9a839d618
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,10.0.0.226", port: 36784 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

I have gone through the official docs and could not find any deprecation notices.

what might be the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Please do not use images to embed output and logs. Paste the text directly with an indentation of 4 spaces. And only paste the relevant parts.

Comment: yeah images have been replaced with text contents

Comment: I made a mistake using remote ip address in the bindIp configuration option. that's why it is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand this line from the log correctly

```
2018-06-25T05:13:43.201+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1390 port=36784 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-10-0-1-69
```

the host's ip is `10.0.1.69` and not `10.0.0.226`. That would explain the error.

Comment: Yes, that is Private IP address of the EC2 instance in the public subnet. So, the api server will be in the public server which needs to interact with MongoDB server in the private subnet. So, rather than using 0.0.0.0 in the bindIp configuration option, I want to use localhost and the IP address of the api server EC2 instance Ip address to be allowed to the MongoDB server.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. Can you just not just use it then?